# Cordova Camera Image Not Uploading Using File Transfer

Tags: angularjs, cordova, file-transfer

The idea of what I'm currently doing is that you can take a photo or select one from the gallery and upload it to a server. I was having trouble with using the cordova `FileTransfer` to send and upload the image. It was either not sending at all or `$_FILES["file"]` would be empty.

I have separate buttons to bring up the camera and gallery:

```
<button id="takePicture" name="takePicture" ng-click="openCamera();">Take Photo</button>
<button id="getPicture" name="getPicture" ng-click="openGallery();">Choose From Gallery</button>
```

**Solution:**

```
$scope.openCamera = function()
{
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onError, 
    {   quality         : 100, 
        destinationType : Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI
    });  

    function onSuccess(imageURI) 
    { 
        var options = new FileUploadOptions();

        options.fileKey     = "file";
        options.fileName    = imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
        options.mimeType    = "image/jpeg";
        options.httpMethod  = "POST";
        options.chunkedMode = false;
        options.params      = { filePath : imageURI.split("?")[0] };

        var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer;

        fileTransfer.upload(imageURI, encodeURI("upload.php"), uploadComplete, uploadError, options);

        function uploadComplete(result) 
        {
            console.log("Code = " + result.responseCode);
            console.log("Response = " + result.response);
            console.log("Sent = " + result.bytesSent);
        }

        function uploadError(error) 
        {
            alert("An error has occurred: Code = " + error.code);
            console.log("upload error source " + error.source);
            console.log("upload error target " + error.target);
        }
    }  

    function onError(message) 
    { 
        alert("fail");

        alert('Failed because: ' + message); 
    } 
}
```

The data sent will then be received on the `upload.php` file. You should be able to check if the data has been sent by inspecting the files `var_dump($_FILES);`

As [Sletheren](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8343272/sletheren) mentioned it can also be done using `$cordovaFileTransfer.upload();`

Answer (score 0):

This is how it works on my side:

- First thing: The `destinationType` should be `Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI`,
- Second: Set the filename to:  `filename = imageURI.split('?')[0];`
- Third: the fileTransfer takes these arguments (it works on my side) :
  `$cordovaFileTransfer.upload(url, filename, options)`

Comment: I'll give this a go now. Thanks! `$cordovaFileTransfer();` works the same as `ft.upload();` doesn't it?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly, been a while since I last used Ionic 1.x, if doesn't work on `ft.upload` then you can rollb-back to `$cordovaFileTransfer`

Comment: I am trying to print out `$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]` but I am currently getting `Undefined index: file`

Comment: try to inspect the value of `filename` before its sent to the server first

Comment: filename is populated. It seems that `imageURI.split('?')[0];` retrieves the filepath and `imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf("/")+1);` retrieves the filename but i'm not quite sure why `$_FILES["file"]` is still empty.

Comment: did you change the destination type to `FILE_URI` ?

Comment: I did but I managed to figure out what the problem was. Thanks for all your help! I will update the question now to show my answer.